# Behat: Goutte/Guzzle downloading file via cURL "Warning: curl_setopt_array(): 3607 is not a valid File-Handle resource"

Tags: php, curl, behat, guzzle, goutte

Using Behat to test some behavior that involves downloading a file. Using Goutte and Guzzle to intercept the file download so I can interact with it in another step.

```
//Where to put the file
$tmpFile = 'download.zip';
$handle  = fopen($tmpFile, 'w');

$goutteDriver = $this->getSession()->getDriver();
$goutteClient = $goutteDriver->getClient();

/** @var \Guzzle\Http\Client $guzzleClient */
$guzzleClient = $goutteClient->getClient();
$guzzleClient->getConfig()->set('curl.options', [CURLOPT_FILE => $handle]);
$guzzleClient->setSslVerification(false);

$goutteDriver->visit($url);

fclose($handle);
```

It works fine, but if I run two different scenarios in a row that run this same step, I get the error:

> "Warning: curl_setopt_array(): 3607 is not a valid File-Handle resource"

Edit: I tried not closing the $handle, and then every scenario after it just skips instead of running. Also tried using `$guzzleClient->getConfig()->remove('curl.options');` and that caused a later step to not work.

Edit2: Example of problem:

I took out all other steps except the one that I've included the code for here, the download of the zip file.

My feature now essentially looks like this:

```
 Background:
   Given I am logged in as an admin

 Scenario: A
    When I click "Export All"

 Scenario: B
    When I click "Export All"
```

When I run it, the output looks like this:

```
  Background:                        
    Given I am logged in as an admin

  Scenario: A
    When I click "Export All" 

  Scenario: B

Warning: curl_setopt_array(): supplied argument is not a valid File-Handle resource in C:\wamp\www\cems2\vendor\guzzle\guzzle\src\Guzzle\Http\Curl\CurlHandle.php on line 219

Call Stack:
    0.0000     131776   1. {main}() C:\wamp\www\cems2\vendor\behat\behat\bin\behat:0
    0.0360    1699576   2. Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run() C:\wamp\www\cems2\vendor\behat\behat\bin\behat:32


When I click "Export All" (skipped)
```

Followed by a stack trace that I can't find any reference to any of my code in.  Full stack trace is here: http://pastebin.com/Fv48gdYm

Comment: Sounds like fopen is failing the second time around, and $handle === false.  You can obviously test for that.  Why is it failing -  Is the file in use?  Are the scenarios running concurrently and trying to write to the same file at the same time?

Comment: The error actually happens before the step, it happens before the first step of the next scenario can even happen. They run one after another.

Comment: Where does the error occur, I assumed on the `set curl.options` line in the above code.

Comment: No, it occurs immediately when the next scenario runs. As far as I can tell, in some kind of setup for the next scenario. The stack trace does not point to any of my code...

Comment: The first one runs, all steps pass, then the second scenarios prints the title, then immediately error. If I run each one on it's own no error.

Comment: I've added an example to the question

Answer (score 0):

I removed the part that was setting the curl opt file, and instead just read the content of the response into the file handle.

```
//Where to put the file
$tmpFile = 'download.zip';
$handle  = fopen($tmpFile, 'w');

$goutteDriver = $this->getSession()->getDriver();
$goutteClient = $goutteDriver->getClient();

/** @var \Guzzle\Http\Client $guzzleClient */
$guzzleClient = $goutteClient->getClient();

//Remove this
//$guzzleClient->getConfig()->set('curl.options', [CURLOPT_FILE => $handle]);

$guzzleClient->setSslVerification(false);

$goutteDriver->visit($url);

//Add this
fwrite($handle, $goutteDriver->getContent());
fclose($handle);
```

And now everything works perfectly.

Comment: You should be able to simplify the top and bottom two lines of code to this:

    file_put_contents('download.zip', $goutteDriver->getContent());

Comment: Thanks @elazar ! Done!